# programmatically copy and delete files on a usb stick which connected to an android tablet

Tags: android, usb, file-transfer

The title pretty much covers my question. I want to connect a USB-Stick to an Android powered tablet (OTG cable).

In my app i want to provide an option to copy a txt-file from a specific folder on my tablet to the connected USB-Stick. This option should also check, if there already is a txt-file on the Stick (not the exact same filename, just similar) and delete that file, so i only have exactly 1 file (txt-file) on that USB-Stick.

I can imagine, deleting stuff on a USB-Stick isn't supported at all since it creates security issues, but if the copying was possible, that already would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html

Comment: Thank You :) So if i got it right, there is no official API to access some removable storage. I just can do it, if i know the name of the folder that represents the removable storage, which of course can change accordingly with the android device and the storage itself.

Comment: "I just can do it, if i know the name of the folder that represents the removable storage" -- not on Android 4.4 and higher. On those versions, you can write to select Android-created directories for your app, but nowhere else.